# Adding Record Three times Entity Framework Why

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using a class DB Context to create my data access layer their I have some business logic to get the lattest student if one does not exist with a recordID-1 i create a new one.

```
public Student GetStudentById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Student studentRecord;
            if (id == -1)
            {
                studentRecord = new Student();
                schoolEntities.AddToStudents(studentRecord);
                SaveChanges();

            }
            else
            {
                studentRecord = (from student in schoolEntities.Students
                                     where student.Student_ID== id
                                     select student).FirstOrDefault();

            }

            return studentRecord;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetStudentById Failed", ex);
        }
}
```

Then on my web page I am doing the following

```
public partial class admin_students_edit : System.Web.UI.Page     
{
      public  SISDBContext _db = new SISDBContext();
      private Student _student;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            int id =Convert.ToInt32( Request.QueryString["id"]);
            _student = _db.GetStudentById(id);


              if(!IsPostBack)
            {


                txtStudentName.Text = _student.Student_Name;
                txtStudentName.Text = _student.Student_FatherName;
                txtRegistrationNo.Text = _student.Registration_no;
                txtAddress1.Text = _student.Address1;
                txtAddress2.Text = _student.Address2;
                txtAddress3.Text=_student.Address3;
                txtRelationshipGurdan.Text= _student.RelationWithGuadian;
                txtGurdianName.Text= _student.GurdianName ;
                txtLastSchool.Text = _student.LastSchoolAtten;



            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     try    
        {
           _student.Student_Name = txtStudentName.Text;
           _student.Student_FatherName = txtStudentName.Text;
           _student.Registration_no = txtRegistrationNo.Text;
           _student.Address1 = txtAddress1.Text.Trim();
           _student.Address2 = txtAddress2.Text.Trim();
           _student.Address3 = txtAddress3.Text.Trim();
           _student.RelationWithGuadian = txtRelationshipGurdan.Text.Trim();
           _student.GurdianName = txtGurdianName.Text.Trim();
           _student.LastSchoolAtten = txtLastSchool.Text.Trim();

           _student.DOB = rdDOB.SelectedDate.Value;


          _db.SaveChanges();
          Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

        }
    }
```

For some reason it is saving the record three times I do not no why because obv I need to save the blank record if one does not exist was wondering if someone could help me out think my logic is miss placed somewhere.

Comment: You assigned `txtStudentName.Text` twice.

Comment: I can not understand your code at all, why call _db.GetStudentById(id) in page load, it call every time that your page refresh, and always send Request Query value. So if the value is -1 it always send -1 and create new row. So create twice in page load and once in button click. You should refactor your code

Comment: Have you tried stepping through using a debugger or adding logging to trace where the calls are coming from? Any chance you're registering your click event multiple times?

Comment: And as an aside, you should never have an empty catch block. At a minimum you should log the exception.

Comment: @MikeParkhill bare with me i am new to EF where is best then to create the blank record obv not in GetStudentByiD where should i call this then instead

Comment: @MikeParkhill I am using GetStudentByiD to fill the student entity if a record their does not exist then create one the step I am missing is how do i return the id into my save event